# Sharepoint 2010 Navigation link drop down not working after select page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, sharepoint-2013

I have creating Sharepoint 2010 Designer page. i have  Global Navigation and current navigation LIke this

```
ContainerGlobal Navigation
SOX Module
    Exception Tracker
    RCM
    LinkReports
    LinkTesting
Current Navigation
    Access and Roles Management
    HeadingInternal Audit Module
    HeadingLists
    HeadingReporting Module
    HeadingRisk Assessment Module
    SOX Module
       Exception Tracker
        RCM
       Reports
       Testing
```

I have created Global and current link like this   both under SOX Module  Global and Navigation all Link url same.when i click drop down global navigation sox module  under link after redirect page  that time drop down menu not working only working Heading SOX Module.
  how to fix this issues i want all page Drop Down  Global navigation menu  i am using V4.master page. please any one Help  how to fix this issues .